# Accessing MySQLi results data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First I would like to apologize if this question has been asked before, but I looked for days and couldn't find anything that I understood as a solution.

I am working on a project for my fantasy football team archives. I have made a graphic playoff tree listed by playoff seed numbers. I have a table for the super bowl results, one for the toilet bowl results, and one for yearly team standings where I have the team names, records and playoff seeds listed. I figured out that the way my tables are set up I have make individual queries on each table by year to pull out the data. The end goal is to be able to display the team names and and scores in this graphic playoff tree, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to access any information in the query results. I want to be able to cross reference team names and scores by the seed #. I thought I could just query the team names and seed # from the yearly standings and put those in two dimensional array that I could use to pull the team name out from the seed #, but I can't figure out how to do that either. I guess that's where the biggest obstacle is right now as the super bowl and toilet bowl results are only one row and I can pull that data out by just accessing the column name, but the yearly standing will be ten rows and two columns.

Can someone tell me how I could pull the team names out by referencing the seed#?

Comment: please show code. where you are facing problem and what you expected as an output? this paragraph writing not going to help you thanks.

Comment: Can you say what's missing from (presumably) every single example that discusses fetching MySQL results into a php array?

Comment: I found something that seems to work for me. 
I tried posting the code, but it keeps telling it's too long by 265 charachters.